# How to search google drive for file with a specific property

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'm using google drive api and trying to search for files that have a property. 
Is it possible to do something like this properties has { key='NoteId'}. I just want to find files that have the property. I don't know the value so I can and don't want to search by value. This is php google app engine code.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this recently? I currently have this question for both the v2 and v3 version of the same REST API. A query like the one from the example in https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters without a 'value' parameter currently responds with a 400 error.

It's worth adding for anyone who comes across this question that if you're in the design phase of an app, you can add another flag property that always has the value `true`, which avoids this issue completely. If there are files out there that have already been created, though this question matters.

Comment: @jpolitz Your comment helped me. I was having a 400 error, and since the API documentation no longer has examples that use `properties` in the query string, I was facing a wall. `key` and `value` and `visibility` are apparently required.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide something like this:

```
"properties has { key='additionalID' and value='8e8aceg2af2ge72e78' and visibility='PRIVATE' }"
```

as described in [Search for Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters) to the `q` parameter in [drive.files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list).

Comment: Note that this doesn't answer the question, which specifically asks for a query that _doesn't_ need to specify the value.

Comment: Thank you @jpolitz.  I thought I understood the question.  If you come up with the answer. I will upvote yours.